# Examining antibody - target interactions in PyMOL

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, microbiology, immunology, pymol

I'm a student currently looking at antibody responses against a viral target protein of interest.

I have my own, annotated PyMOL session of my protein and I also have .pdbs of crystallised antibody structures that bind to this protein and rougly know whereabouts it binds. I would like to know if it is possible to combine these two structures into a single session to observe or at least overlay the two structures together. Many thanks!

Comment: You might find a PyMol expert on this list. If not try SE Bioinformatics or even Chemistry.

Comment: I don't think PyMOL has built-in functions for that; you might have to use a docking software like AutoDock. I'd also recommend asking on Bioinformatics SE as David suggested

Answer (score 1):

Multiple structures may be read into a given session using the following for each pdb:

```
File -> Open
```

In the narrative below, the reference antibody has the name AAA and the second antibody has the name BBB. The heavy and light chains have pdb chain IDs A and B, respectively. Adjust those as needed.

**Whole molecule overlay**

Make visible the reference and the moving molecules.
From the menu item next to the BBB molecule name (right panel), select:

```
A -> align -> to molecule (*/CA) -> Object: AAA
```

**Antibody's variable domain overlay**

I think it may be more helpful to align the variable domains than the whole antibodies or Fabs. Typing the following on the command line is a temporarily adequate way to align proteins:

```
align BBB and chain A+B and res 1:109, AAA and chain A+BL and res 1:109
```